# Transposing music using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chord chart application that I wrote and I would like to allow users to transpose the key of the chart using an onClick handler.

My chart looks like this

```
{C}My name is Blanket, {F}And I can run fast
```

The chords inside the brackets appear above the letter it preceeds.

I would like to use javascript or jquery in order to do this. How would I go about creating this transpose button? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

So here's what I came up with...

```
$('.transposeUp').click(function(){
    $('.chord').each(function(){
        var currentChord = $(this).text(); // gathers the chord being used
        if(currentChord == $(this).text()){
        var chord = $(this).text().replace("F#", "G")
        }
        //... the if statements continue though every chord
        //but I didn't place them here to save space
    });
});
```

So here is the problem...

I have a slash chord in the mix (G/B), It changes the be on transpose but because it changes the "B" the chord is now (G/C) which is not the same as the "currentChord" so it doesn't change the G when it gets to its respective if condition. Until I have transposed enough where the Chord is eventualy (G/G) then the first "G" starts transposing leaving the last "G" the same. Any ideas? Again your knowledge and help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: none thus far. I know that I can grab the chords via .text(). Ya know I forgot to mention that the code generates strong tags around the chord too. but that is all I have. Can you help me with the logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to match the chords sequentially so that you can update them one at a time.  If you try to match everything at once you'll run into problems like you described, because you keep matching the same chord over and over again.

A good way to accomplish this would be with regular expressions to parse and split the chord.  Once you have the matching chord values, use an array of chords to find the next/previous chord to transpose.  Here is some sample code I have developed as a demo:

```
<p><span class="chord">{C}</span>My name is Blanket,</p>
<p><span class="chord">{G / B}</span>And I can run fast</p>

<p>
<input id="transposeDown" type="button" value="Down" /> |
<input id="transposeUp" type="button" value="Up" />
</p>

var match;
var chords =
    ['C','C#','D','Eb','E','F','F#','G','Ab','A','Bb','B','C',
     'Db','D','D#','E','F','Gb','G','G#','A','A#','C'];
var chordRegex = /C#|D#|F#|G#|A#|Db|Eb|Gb|Ab|Bb|C|D|E|F|G|A|B/g;

$('#transposeUp').click(function() {
    $('.chord').each(function() {
        var currentChord = $(this).text();
        var output = "";
        var parts = currentChord.split(chordRegex);
        var index = 0;
        while (match = chordRegex.exec(currentChord))
        {
            var chordIndex = chords.indexOf(match[0]);
            output += parts[index++] + chords[chordIndex+1];
        }
        output += parts[index];
        $(this).text(output);
    });
});

$('#transposeDown').click(function() {
    $('.chord').each(function() {
        var currentChord = $(this).text();
        var output = "";
        var parts = currentChord.split(chordRegex);
        var index = 0;
        while (match = chordRegex.exec(currentChord))
        {
            var chordIndex = chords.indexOf(match[0],1);
            output += parts[index++] + chords[chordIndex-1];
        }
        output += parts[index];
        $(this).text(output);
    });
});
```

**Sample demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4kYQZ/2/

A couple of things to notice:

1. I took @gregp's idea of having multiple copies of the key list so that I can handle both sharps and flats.  The first scale includes the preferred #/b which will be used during transposing.  The second scale includes the other formats so that if the music includes them, they will transpose correctly.  For instance, since Eb is in the first scale, it will be used instead of D# as you are transposing up and down; however, if there is a D# in the music to begin with, it will correctly move to D/E (with the caveat that if you move back, it will become an Eb again).  Feel free to modify the preferred scale - I used my educated judgment based on personal music experience.
2. The regular expression has to have the sharped/flatted keys first, otherwise a `C#` would be just as easily matched as a `C` when that's not correct.
3. I have `C` at the beginning and the end of the array so that I can start at any location and move both directions without passing the end of the array.  In order for this to work, the transposeDown code has an extra parameter in the call to `chords.indexOf` to start at position 1 so it matches the last `C` in the array instead of the first `C`.  Then when it attempts to move to the previous element, it doesn't pass the beginning of the array.
4. I'm splitting the chord as well using the regular expression, which is redundant, but it makes it super-easy to recompose the final string back together - by interleaving the original string parts with the updated chord keys (don't forget the last piece at the end!).
5. I'm using elements instead of classes for your buttons.

Hope this helps!

---

**Update 1:** Per comment by OP, the use of `indexOf` on arrays is not supported by pre-ie9.  This can be solved by using a helper function that does the same thing:

```
function arrayIndexOf(arr, match)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == match)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

And this line

```
var chordIndex = chords.indexOf(match[0]);
```

would be replaced with:

```
var chordIndex = arrayIndexOf(chords, match[0]);
```

See updated sample demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4kYQZ/11/

Comment: Wow thank you soooo much, this helped alot. It really did occur to me to use regex, but I am not real familiar with it as I have only recently started playing with it. Thank You so much, really!

Comment: One more thing, i would like to modify the scales to where if I am in "Ab" all notes are flats. Would I need to create individual scales and a Key type input and associate the scales and keys or is there a way to determine the key based on the chords in the song then choose the resp. scale, or is there a better logic. I promise I am not just fishing for code, I really want to learn how and why I am doing these things as I have studied your previous funtion to do just that. Any help (including just logic) is appreciated. thank you very much sir.

Comment: nevermind, I found a quick and easy fix. I changed all of the first chords in the "chords array" to sharps then flats then I created a second "array" that contained just the opposite flats then sharps. Now if someone transposes up, everything is in sharps and if they transpose down then everything is in flats. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have been using this for a while now and It works beautifully, but I have recently realized that it does not work in ie8 or below. I have been told that it is because indexOf is not supported in those browsers. I have tried to implement my own method of indexOf but to no avail. Is there a way this can be rewritten where it will be fully cross browser?

Comment: Thanks, I found this last night and then realized that ie8 and below is not fully compatible with .split either, so I had to rewrite that method as well. Split handles normal arrays in ie, but it does not handle regex very well, so I had to find a solution for it as well. Thanks, for trying to help!

Comment: Is there a way to do this same thing in php

Comment: Should be fairly easy to do.  I would work through the code line-by-line and look for PHP methods that are similar to the JavaScript method.  Most of the functionality is standard to PHP, but the arguments and logic may be slightly different. If you get stuck on a certain part or something, I would recommend starting a new question specific to your issue.

Comment: I have one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632901/see-if-a-value-exists-within-a-group-in-regex-and-then-manipulate-it-within-the/12633278#12633278 I got stuck...

Comment: Another note. If you try to "transposeDown" from the key of "C", it shows up as "undefined" I think because this is the first position of the array and it cannot find the value to the left of the first position.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you're spoiled for choice for binding click handlers. There's .click(), .delegate(), .live(), and many others. It wouldn't make sense to reproduce what the APIs already tell you, but I can say this: learning how to bind the click is the smallest part of the overall problem, and even capturing the chord name with .text() is going to be trivial once you've had a look at the jQuery API.

The tricky part is going to be the logic of transposing itself. You'll need to take the knowledge you already have (for example, going from E to F is only a half-step; there's no E# or Fb) and make it work as code.

My apologies for general advice rather than code samples, but my advice is to have two arrays, one containing all the chords in terms of sharps, one with all the chords in terms of flats.

You could do a bit of cheating, too: instead of logic to wrap around to the beginning (say, C in position 0), just have your arrays duplicated:

["C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","B"]

Then find the first occurence of the chord name, move ahead the desired number of stops, and you'll still have the right string.

Comment: thank you so much, i'll see what I can come up with and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Call function transpose for up:

```
text = transpose(text, 1);
```

Call function transpose for down:

```
text = transpose(text, -1);
```

Function:

```
function transpose(text, amount){
   var lines = new Array();
   var chord = new Array();
   var scale =  ["C","Cb","C#","D","Db","D#","E","Eb","E#","F","Fb","F#","G","Gb","G#",
                 "A","Ab","A#","B","Bb","B#"];
   var transp = ["Cb","C","C#","Bb","Cb","C","C","C#","D","Db","D","D#","C","Db","D",
                 "D","D#","E","Eb","E","F","D","Eb","E","E","E#","F#","E","F","F#", 
                 "Eb","Fb","F","F","F#","G","Gb","G","G#","F","Gb","G","G","G#","A", 
                 "Ab","A","A#", "G","Ab","A","A","A#","B","Bb","B","C","A","Bb","B",
                 "B","B#","C#"];
  var inter = '';
  var mat = '';
  lines = text.split("\n");
  for(var i in lines){
      if(i%2===0){
         chord = lines[i].split(" ");
         for(var x in chord){
             if(chord[x]!==""){
               inter = chord[x];
               var subst = inter.match(/[^b#][#b]?/g);
               for(var ax in subst){
                   if(scale.indexOf(subst[ax])!==-1){
                      if(amount>0){
                         for(ix=0;ix<amount;ix++){
                             var pos = scale.indexOf(subst[ax]);
                             var transpos = 3*pos-2+3;
                             subst[ax] = transp[transpos+1];
                         }
                      }
                      if(amount<0){
                         for(ix=0;ix>amount;ix--){
                             var pos = scale.indexOf(subst[ax]);
                             var transpos = 3*pos-2+3;
                             subst[ax] = transp[transpos-1];
                            }
                     }
                  } 
               }
               chord[x]=subst.join("");
           }
        }
       lines[i] = chord.join(" ");
    }
  }
  return lines.join("\n");
}
```

The first line is transpose and the second does not, and sequentially.